# calling non static method from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-applications, non-static

Hi my function is where i need to upload a xml file and check in the folder the file exist or not.
If the file exist i need to replace the file with a pop up in javascript by using ok or cancel and then from the button click i need to save the xml file and bind in a grid. Now im able to save the file but im not able to bind into the grid. Thanks.

My File upload code

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile){
        if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "text/xml")
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
            string path = Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Path"]) + filename;
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "", "ConfirmBox();", true);
                ExistPath = path;
                Session["FileUpload1"] = FileUpload1;
                Session["GridView1"] = GridView1;

            }
            else
            {
                SaveXml(path);
            }
        }
}
```

Javascript

```
<script language="javascript"  type="text/javascript">
    function ConfirmBox() {
        if (confirm("Do you want to overrite")) {
            PageMethods.FileExist(document.getElementById('<%=hfConfirmValue.ClientID %>').value);                  
        }           
    }

</script>
```

The page method

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static string FileExist(string confirm)
{
    #region Save XML
    string path = ExistPath;
    FileUpload s = HttpContext.Current.Session["FileUpload1"] as FileUpload;
    GridView g = HttpContext.Current.Session["GridView1"] as GridView;
    s.SaveAs(path);        
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(Path.GetFullPath(path));
    GlobalDS = ds;      
    g.DataSource = ds;
    g.DataBind();        
    return "file updated";
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Surely you're missing some *really important* tags here? Like `asp.net` and such?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder as i know i didnt miss any tags.it can save but just not displaying in the grid now.

Comment: No no -- tags *on the question*. Those bits in blue at the bottom. Tag the relevant techologies (`asp.net`, ETC.).

Comment: What I am understanding is that your page is not getting refreshed after making ajax call right? Do this FileExist function is calling or not? try to make any false button click and bind grid again on it and check for a moment that grid is binding or not?